# Delphi, what controls to use instead of many pairs of checkbox and combobox?

Tags: delphi, controls

I have a variable list of pairs TCheckBox+TComboBox. It has some flaws: you cannot select several pairs for batch modification, they are created slowly when their number is large (100-200 pairs). Is it possible to replace them with more appropriate control(s)?

[image]

Comment: There's the Virtual String Tree third-party control which is extremely flexible in this nature.

Comment: Have you considered of removing the checkboxes and adding an empty value to ComboBoxes to represent a unchecked checkbox status? This is assuming that you use your checkboxes to determine whether you even need the value of combo box or not.

Comment: And instead of using multiple ComboBoxes, maybe use a single `TValueListEditor` instead

Comment: @Jerry Dodge I use it in other places, I will check if it can be used in this case

Comment: @SilverWarior TCheckBox is needed to show that this "line" is used and and enables/disables TComboxBox. The meaning of empty value would not be obvious for the customer. Also you'll get the same problem if you have two times more controls

Comment: @Remy TValueListEditor has no checkboxes, I dont see how it can be used with checkboxes

Comment: But nevertheless, what you could and should use is rather a recommendation and these are off-topic.

Comment: Not quite the solution for all the problems here, but ccpack allows you to create composite controls, so you could create a control that has both, the checkbox and the combobox, and then you only need to create one control per line rather than two. It could also wrap some code for both.

Comment: @Molochnik no, TValueListEditor does not have checkboxes. But you don't need them if you designate a ComboxBox item for "not used". It doesn't have to be empty, just clear in what it means.

Comment: @dummzeuch the same thing can be done using a standard VCL TFrame instead

Comment: Instead of empty, you can also put an explicit value like '< not modified >' , '< pick one >'  in the combobox. From a user's perspective it's way better, because they have fewer clicks to make. The checkbox is only maybe more clear for first time users, but this looks like an expert tool to me.

Comment: @dummzeuch Actually I use small panels containing both controls for proper alignment, so totally 3 controls per "line". Frames do no better - too many controls.

Comment: Ok if I drop checkboxes as well as panels which are of no use now, then I'll have 3 times less controls at the expense of some visual convenience (checked/unchecked checkboxes are seen clearly unlike different text values)

Comment: Finally I did as @Jerry Dodge said - used TVirtualStringTree, added ComboBox editor and everything looks and works perfectly